# Cropping UIimage in IOS

Tags: ios

I am very new to IOS and the first task given to me is Image cropping. means If I am using an image as banner image and the given frame size is more then or smaller thn the size of the image . my code should automatically resize image in respective aspect ratio of the image and then set image in that frame.

I have done so much R&D and after that i have written code.

```
-(UIImage *)MyScaleNEwMethodwithImage:(UIImage *)image andframe:(CGRect)frame{

float bmHeight= image.size.height;
float bmWidth= image.size.width;

UIImage *RecievedImage=image;
    if (bmHeight>bmWidth) {

    float ratio = frame.size.height/frame.size.width;
    float newbmHeight = ratio*bmWidth;
    float cropedHeight= (bmHeight-newbmHeight)/2;

    if (cropedHeight<0) {

        float ratio1= frame.size.width/frame.size.height;
        float newbmHeight1= (ratio1*bmHeight);
        float cropedimageHeight1 = (bmWidth- newbmHeight1)/2;

        CGRect cliprect = CGRectMake(cropedimageHeight1, 0,bmWidth-cropedimageHeight1,bmHeight);
        CGImageRef imref = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([image CGImage],cliprect);
        UIImage *newSubImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imref];
        return  newSubImage;
 }
    else

    {
    CGRect cliprect = CGRectMake(0,cropedHeight,bmWidth,bmHeight-cropedHeight);
       CGImageRef imref = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([image CGImage],cliprect);
        UIImage *newSubImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imref];
        return  newSubImage;
    }
}
else
{
    float ratio = frame.size.height/frame.size.width;
    float newbmHeight = ratio*bmHeight;
    float cropedHeight= (bmHeight-newbmHeight)/4;

    if (cropedHeight<0) {
        float ratio1= frame.size.width/frame.size.height;
        float newbmHeight1= (ratio1*bmWidth);
        float cropedimageHeight1 = (bmWidth- newbmHeight1)/2;

        UIImageView *DummyImage=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,cropedimageHeight1,bmWidth,(bmHeight-cropedimageHeight1))];
        [DummyImage setImage:RecievedImage];

        CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([DummyImage.image CGImage], CGRectMake(0,cropedimageHeight1/2,bmWidth/2,(bmHeight-cropedimageHeight1)/2));
        // or use the UIImage wherever you like
        [DummyImage setImage:[UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef]];
        CGImageRelease(imageRef);
        UIImage *ScaledImage=[UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
        return ScaledImage;


 } else {

        UIImageView *DummyImage=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(cropedHeight,0,bmWidth-cropedHeight,bmHeight)];
        [DummyImage setImage:RecievedImage];

        CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([DummyImage.image CGImage],CGRectMake(cropedHeight,2*cropedHeight,(bmWidth-cropedHeight),bmHeight/2));
        // or use the UIImage wherever you like
        [DummyImage setImage:[UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef]];
        CGImageRelease(imageRef);
        UIImage *ScaledImage=[UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
        return ScaledImage;


    }
}

}
```

In my frame i am getting required image but when screen changes i can see full image. i want to cut the unwanted image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thise piece of code may help you out

```
-(CGRect) cropImage:(CGRect)frame
{
    NSAssert(self.contentMode == UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit, @"content mode should be aspect fit");

    CGFloat wScale = self.bounds.size.width / self.image.size.width;
    CGFloat hScale = self.bounds.size.height / self.image.size.height;

    float x, y, w, h, offset;
    if (wScale<hScale) {
        offset = (self.bounds.size.height - (self.image.size.height*widthScale))/2;
        x = frame.origin.x / wScale;
        y = (frame.origin.y-offset) / wScale;
        w = frame.size.width / wScale;
        h = frame.size.height / wScale;
    } else {
        offset = (self.bounds.size.width - (self.image.size.width*heightScale))/2;
        x = (frame.origin.x-offset) / hScale;
        y = frame.origin.y / hScale;
        w = frame.size.width / hScale;
        h = frame.size.height / hScale;
    }
    return CGRectMake(x, y, w, h);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code which I had referred to crop the image as per aspect ratio is :

```
typedef enum {
    MGImageResizeCrop,  
    MGImageResizeCropStart,
    MGImageResizeCropEnd,
    MGImageResizeScale  
} MGImageResizingMethod;


 - (UIImage *)imageToFitSize:(CGSize)fitSize method:(MGImageResizingMethod)resizeMethod
    {
        float imageScaleFactor = 1.0;
    #if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= 40000
        if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(scale)]) {
            imageScaleFactor = [self scale];
        }
    #endif

        float sourceWidth = [self size].width * imageScaleFactor;
        float sourceHeight = [self size].height * imageScaleFactor;
        float targetWidth = fitSize.width;
        float targetHeight = fitSize.height;
        BOOL cropping = !(resizeMethod == MGImageResizeScale);

        // Calculate aspect ratios
        float sourceRatio = sourceWidth / sourceHeight;
        float targetRatio = targetWidth / targetHeight;

        // Determine what side of the source image to use for proportional scaling
        BOOL scaleWidth = (sourceRatio <= targetRatio);
        // Deal with the case of just scaling proportionally to fit, without cropping
        scaleWidth = (cropping) ? scaleWidth : !scaleWidth;

        // Proportionally scale source image
        float scalingFactor, scaledWidth, scaledHeight;
        if (scaleWidth) {
            scalingFactor = 1.0 / sourceRatio;
            scaledWidth = targetWidth;
            scaledHeight = round(targetWidth * scalingFactor);
        } else {
            scalingFactor = sourceRatio;
            scaledWidth = round(targetHeight * scalingFactor);
            scaledHeight = targetHeight;
        }
        float scaleFactor = scaledHeight / sourceHeight;

        // Calculate compositing rectangles
        CGRect sourceRect, destRect;
        if (cropping) {
            destRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, targetWidth, targetHeight);
            float destX, destY;
            if (resizeMethod == MGImageResizeCrop) {
                // Crop center
                destX = round((scaledWidth - targetWidth) / 2.0);
                destY = round((scaledHeight - targetHeight) / 2.0);
            } else if (resizeMethod == MGImageResizeCropStart) {
                // Crop top or left (prefer top)
                if (scaleWidth) {
                    // Crop top
                    destX = 0.0;
                    destY = 0.0;
                } else {
                    // Crop left
                    destX = 0.0;
                    destY = round((scaledHeight - targetHeight) / 2.0);
                }
            } else if (resizeMethod == MGImageResizeCropEnd) {
                // Crop bottom or right
                if (scaleWidth) {
                    // Crop bottom
                    destX = round((scaledWidth - targetWidth) / 2.0);
                    destY = round(scaledHeight - targetHeight);
                } else {
                    // Crop right
                    destX = round(scaledWidth - targetWidth);
                    destY = round((scaledHeight - targetHeight) / 2.0);
                }
            }
            sourceRect = CGRectMake(destX / scaleFactor, destY / scaleFactor, 
                                    targetWidth / scaleFactor, targetHeight / scaleFactor);
        } else {
            sourceRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, sourceWidth, sourceHeight);
            destRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, scaledWidth, scaledHeight);
        }

        // Create appropriately modified image.
        UIImage *image = nil;
    #if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= 40000
        if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 4.0) {
            UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(destRect.size, NO, 0.0); // 0.0 for scale means "correct scale for device's main screen".
            CGImageRef sourceImg = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([self CGImage], sourceRect); // cropping happens here.
            image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:sourceImg scale:0.0 orientation:self.imageOrientation]; // create cropped UIImage.
            [image drawInRect:destRect]; // the actual scaling happens here, and orientation is taken care of automatically.
            CGImageRelease(sourceImg);
            image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
        }
    #endif
        if (!image) {
            // Try older method.
            CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
            CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, fitSize.width, fitSize.height, 8, (fitSize.width * 4), 
                                                         colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);
            CGImageRef sourceImg = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([self CGImage], sourceRect);
            CGContextDrawImage(context, destRect, sourceImg);
            CGImageRelease(sourceImg);
            CGImageRef finalImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);    
            CGContextRelease(context);
            CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
            image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:finalImage];
            CGImageRelease(finalImage);
        }

        return image;
    }
```

Check if this helps you.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable answer but the thing is that in my project I am using Image cropping as a big thing so it won't work there'